# Ubuntu install not seeing hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a dumb problem that I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction on. I'm trying to install ubuntu 16.04.1 on a windows10 machine. I've followed all the steps correctly (I think) all the way up to the point where I am supposed to go through the install program on the thumb drive. The first problem is that it does not show the option screen that has the partition the hard drive options (see here: http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Select-Ubuntu-16.04-Installation-Type.png). The next page (here:http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) only shows that my "device for boot loader installation" is the thumb drive itself.

I'm confused. I've made sure that there is in windows a free partition with no drive assigned and every other step up till the point where I reach this dead end I've followed correctly seemingly. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem on my laptop.  Here's how I fixed it.

Note that the specifics of each step will be different for different computers, and I can't tell you exactly how to do each thing.  If you have questions, I recommend Google.  I can only help you with the specifics if you're using an IBM ThinkPad.

1) Go into the BIOS

2) Go into the settings for the hard drive (usually labeled as `SATA`)

3) Enable compatibility mode

4) Reboot

5) Install Ubuntu

6) Go back into BIOS and put the settings back how they were

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that doesn't work on my machine, I  just checked (Dell XPS 15).

Comment: Alright well my advice would be to go through the BIOS and find anything that says `compatibility` or anything similar to that and select it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have anything like that in mine.

Comment: Aw man :/ sorry I couldn't help you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my Dell XPS 13. Hopefully the same stuff applies.

I had to go into the BIOS settings and make sure that under General > Advanced Boot Options: was set to the UEFI Network Stack option,

Under System Configuration > SATA Operation: was set to AHCI,

And of course make sure secure boot is off. If that doesn't work, let me know. Should be something simple. Hope this helps!

Comment: Turning off raid array damn near bricked my computer. I changed the setting in the other one see if that helps.

Comment: Oh shit! Sorry, I didn't even think to ask if you were using raid! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: meh, I got it changed back, so np. I changed the other setting, but it hasn't fixed the problem. gar :/

Comment: @PeterWeyand 4 years later... do you remember how did you workaround it? I have the same machine and same issue. Ty